# jupyter security directory empty, but jupyter notebook list shows a running server

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I run `jupyter notebook list` I get:

`Currently running servers:
http://localhost:8888/?token=2f349408fa7154054c6f3f63128f3461eb9983ec068726d1 :: /path/to/project`

I checked the `security` directory, where connection files should be stored for the current profile and it's empty.

I tried `jupyter notebook stop` but I get: `No such file or directory: ./stop`

I also tried listing current open connections using fuser and nettop. The connection is not there, and it shouldn't be as I haven't been working on the listed project for a while.

Jupyter version is 5.0.0, running on Mac OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current connections directory I ran `jupyter --paths`, following the [Jupyter common directories and file locations documentation](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html). From there I picked the runtime directory, so I opened it. The directory contained

- notebook_cookie_secret file
- many files with name format:
  kernel-hash_number.json
- one file with name format:
  nbserver-server_number.json

I opened the `nbserver-server_number.json` file, and I checked that the `token` number is the same one as the one given by `jupyter notebook list`. I deleted that file and now Jupyter can't see it as a running server anymore.